# parse color # to 0x in TextView android

Tags: android

I tried this one

```
TextView.setTextColor(0xFF00FF00);
```

and

```
TextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
```

the result is Green.

but I want the code like this,

```
String green= "#00FF00";
TextView.setTextColor(Integer.parse(green));
```

but it's not working.

Regards,

Comment: Correct Way yourTextViewInstance.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#1b90df"));

Comment: sorry, I was wrong to write before, I mean I want to textview.setTextColor(Integer.parse("#00ff00"));

Comment: What is the need for not following an Android Defined Standard way?

Comment: I want using the function `colorToHSV(int color, float[] hsv)` before using the function, I want check from textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
String green= "#00FF00";
TextView.setTextColor(Integer.parseInt(green.split("#")[1], 16) + 0xFF000000);
```

Answer (score 1):

TextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00")); use this line and check.

Comment: sorry, I was wrong to write before, I mean I want to textview.setTextColor(Integer.parse("#00ff00"));
"string to int"